# Handling paper scanner jams using Morena

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, twain, image-scanner

Ive been using the Morena library to scan in documents through a scanned with an ADF using Morenas TWAIN implementation. However I have found a problem when the scanner jams my program will crash and burn. Ive tried searching for some  way to handle this but I just cant see to think of a practical method. If anyone could suggest a way to handle this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you contacted Gnome? They're usually pretty good

Comment: Haven't tried that, i figured id see if the community had anything to offer before i resorted to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twain driver should report a paper jam to the condition code status. In case of a paper jam, it should return TWCC_PAPERJAM=20. Many drivers do not support this feature. You can experiment with the getConditionCode, getResultCode methods on your specific hardware.

ImageConsumer constants are useful in detecting that a problem of some sort has occurred. (You will not be able to detect that it is a paper jam in particular that has occurred, however.) There are three possible status values:

IMAGEABORTED = The image creation process was deliberately aborted.

IMAGEERROR = An error was encountered while producing the image.

STATICIMAGEDONE = The image is complete and there are no more pixels or frames to be delivered.
You can also receive these values using the getStatus method of the MorenaImage class.